# Unable to use html2canvas.js in content script in manifest.json with rollup extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, web-development-server

I'm building chrome extension, just to install firebase version 9 , I decided to use roll up extension that would bundle up everything for me and it did worked fine but, before moving to roll up extension, I was using the following code

````
```
 "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": [
        "contentScript.js",
        "libraries/pdf-lib.js",
        "libraries/html2canvas.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
```
````

And I would use html2canvas in content script and it worked fine, but right now with roll up extension, I've spent good amount of hours and not yet able to use html2canvas in content script, all the time it gives the following error
TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: chrome-extension://ID/libraries/html2canvas.js

Is there any way to use html2canvas.js with rollup extension? or some other solution?

Rollup.config.js

```
import path from "path";

import babel from "@rollup/plugin-babel";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import replace from "@rollup/plugin-replace";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";

import {
  chromeExtension,
  simpleReloader,
} from "rollup-plugin-chrome-extension";
import { emptyDir } from "rollup-plugin-empty-dir";
import zip from "rollup-plugin-zip";

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";

export default {
  input: "src/manifest.json",
  output: {
    dir: "dist",
    format: "esm",
    chunkFileNames: path.join("chunks", "[name]-[hash].js"),
  },
  plugins: [
    chromeExtension(),
    // Adds a Chrome extension reloader during watch mode
    simpleReloader(),
    // Replace environment variables
    replace({
      preventAssignment: true,
      "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
    }),
    babel({
      // Do not transpile dependencies
      ignore: ["node_modules"],
      babelHelpers: "bundled",
    }),
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    // Empties the output dir before a new build
    emptyDir(),
    // Outputs a zip file in ./releases
    isProduction && zip({ dir: "releases" }),
  ],
};
```